# Errors compiling UDF on linux in ANSYS Fluent

Tags: c, user-defined-functions, fluent

I currently use user defined functions in ANSYS Fluent. These are written in C language with some macros specific to fluent. I have working udfs written for windows, and am now trying to run them on a Linux machine. I have received the following errors. I am relatively new to Linux and C, so any help would be appreciated. I have done a lot of troubleshooting thus far, but am still running into errors.

I have already edited the code to solve other errors, these are what are left after editing.

```
 #include "udf.h"

 /*=======================================================================*/
 #define DEPTH_TOP -0.2
 #define DEPTH_BOTTOM -2.0
 #define MU_TOP 18
 #define MU_BOTTOM 1e-3
 #define r 25.0
 #define DIFFUSE_TOP 18
 #define DIFFUSE_BOTTOM 1.43e-6
 #define RP_3D 1

 #ifdef RP_3D
 double anomaly_top_z =  -10.0; 
 double anomaly_bottom_z   =  0.0; 
 double anomaly_accuracy_z   = 0.1; 
 #endif

 /*=======================================================================*/
 enum
 {salinity,
  };
 int is_in_plume(double coords[])
 {
real x = coords[0]; 
real y = coords[1];  /* convenient names for coordinates: horizontal, vertical */

 #ifdef RP_3D
 real z = coords[2];  /* convenient names for coordinates: second horizontal */
#endif

if ((pow((x-125.0),2)+pow((y-125),2))>pow(r,2))   return 0;

if (z < anomaly_top_z + anomaly_accuracy_z)      return 0; 
if (z > anomaly_bottom_z - anomaly_accuracy_z)   return 0; 

return 1; 
 }

 double temp_plume(double coords[]) 
 {
real depth = coords[2];               /* yes, sir - the depth is always the second in coords array */
 real temp_val;   

if (is_in_plume(coords) == 1) {
    temp_val = 298.15;
} else {
    temp_val = 299.15; 
} 
    return temp_val;
 }
 double sal_plume(double coords[]) 
 {
 real depth = coords[2];               /* yes, sir - the depth is always the second in coords array */
real sal_val;   

if (is_in_plume(coords) == 1) {
    sal_val = 7.0;
} else {
    sal_val = 27.0; 
} 
    return sal_val;
 }
 initTemperature(domain);

 DEFINE_INIT(tempplume_init, domain)

 void initTemperature(Domain * domain) 
 {
real coords[ND_ND];                   /* will be used to get coordinares */
real temp_val;                         /* temporary variable */
Thread* thread; 
cell_t cell;
int init_result = 1; 
real depth; 

if (init_result == -1) {
    Error("Initialization failed. \n"); 
} else { 
    Message("Start looping. \n");       
    thread_loop_c(thread, domain)                 /* loop over all types ("threads") of cells in the domain */
    {
        Message("In loop over threads. \n"); 

        begin_c_loop_all(cell, thread)            /* loop over all cells in the thread */
            C_CENTROID(coords, cell, thread);     /* load coordinates of the cell into "coords" array; */

            depth = coords[ND_ND - 1]; 

            temp_val = temp_plume(coords);  

            C_T(cell, thread) = temp_val;  
        end_c_loop_all(cell, thread)              /* end loop over cells */
    }                                             /* end loop over threads */

    Message("Initialization complete. \n"); 
} 
 }
 DEFINE_INIT(salplume_init, domain)
 {
initSalinity(domain);
 }
 void initSalinity(Domain * domain) 
 {
real coords[ND_ND];                   /* will be used to get coordinates */
real sal_val;                         /* temporary variable */
Thread* thread; 
cell_t cell;
int init_result = 1; 
real depth; 

if (init_result == -1) {
    Error("Initialization failed. \n"); 
} else { 
    Message("Start looping. \n");       
    thread_loop_c(thread, domain)                 /* loop over all types ("threads") of cells in the domain */
    {
        Message("In loop over threads. \n"); 

        begin_c_loop_all(cell, thread)            /* loop over all cells in the thread */
            C_CENTROID(coords, cell, thread);     /* load coordinates of the cell into "coords" array; */

            depth = coords[ND_ND - 1]; 

            sal_val = sal_plume(coords);  

            C_UDSI(cell, thread,salinity) = sal_val;  
        end_c_loop_all(cell, thread)              /* end loop over cells */
    }                                             /* end loop over threads */

    Message("Initialization complete. \n"); 
} 
 }
 DEFINE_PROPERTY(salinity_dens,c,t)
 {
real pho_w, sigma_t;
real sal = C_UDSI(c,t,salinity); /* in promilles */
real temp = C_T(c,t) - 273.15; 

/* complex formula - see www.es.flinders.edu.au/~mattom/IntroOc/lecture03.html */

sigma_t = - 0.157406 + temp*(6.793952E-2 - temp*(9.095290E-3 - temp*(1.001685E-4 - temp*(1.120083E-6 - temp 
 *6.536332E-9)))) + 
   sal*(8.24493E-1 - temp*(4.0899E-3 - temp*(7.6438E-5 - temp*(8.2467E-7 - temp*5.3875E-9))) 
   - sqrt(sal)*(5.72466E-3 - temp*(1.0227E-4 - temp*1.6546E-6)) + sal*4.8314E-4);

pho_w = 1000.0 + sigma_t; 
return pho_w;
 }
 DEFINE_PROPERTY(cell_viscosity, c, ct)
 {
real mu_laminar; real depth;

real coords[ND_ND];      /* will be used to get coordinares */

C_CENTROID(coords, c, ct);  
/*depth = coords[1]; */

depth = coords[ND_ND - 1];            /* -2 because y is vertical */

    if (depth > DEPTH_TOP) {
        mu_laminar = MU_TOP;
    } else if (depth < DEPTH_BOTTOM) {
        mu_laminar = MU_BOTTOM;
    } else {
        mu_laminar = MU_BOTTOM + (depth - DEPTH_BOTTOM) * 
               (MU_TOP - MU_BOTTOM)/(DEPTH_TOP -       DEPTH_BOTTOM);
    return mu_laminar;
}

 DEFINE_DIFFUSIVITY(sal_diffuse, c, ct, i)
 {
real diffusivity; real depth;

real coords[ND_ND];      /* will be used to get coordinares */

C_CENTROID(coords, c, ct);  

depth = coords[ND_ND - 2];            /* -2 because y is vertical */

    if (depth > DEPTH_TOP)
        diffusivity = DIFFUSE_TOP;
    else if (depth < DEPTH_BOTTOM)
        diffusivity = DIFFUSE_BOTTOM;
    else 
        diffusivity = DIFFUSE_BOTTOM + (depth - DEPTH_BOTTOM) * 
               (DIFFUSE_TOP - DIFFUSE_BOTTOM)/(DEPTH_TOP - DEPTH_BOTTOM);

    return diffusivity;
 }

 DEFINE_SOURCE(x_mom,c,t,dS,eqn)
 {
real coords[ND_ND];
real y = coords[1]; 
real f; real theta; real source;
theta=10.0*3.14/180.0;
f=2.0*7.2921e-5*sin(theta)*50.0;
source=C_R(c,t)*f*C_V(c,t);
dS[eqn]=0.0;
return source;
 }

 DEFINE_SOURCE(y_mom,c,t,dS,eqn)
 {
real coords[ND_ND];
real x = coords[0]; 
real f; real theta; real source;
theta=10.0*3.14/180.0;
f=-2.0*7.2921e-5*sin(theta)*50.0;
source=C_R(c,t)*f*C_U(c,t);
dS[eqn]=0.0;
return source;
 }

 ..\..\src\cylinder_plume_inccoriolis_viscosity_test.c(69): error C2082: redefinition of formal parameter 'initTemperature'
 ..\..\src\cylinder_plume_inccoriolis_viscosity_test.c(69): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '{'
 ..\..\src\cylinder_plume_inccoriolis_viscosity_test.c(172): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '{'
 ..\..\src\cylinder_plume_inccoriolis_viscosity_test.c(193): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '{'undeclared identifier
 ..\..\src\cylinder_plume_inccoriolis_viscosity_test.c(199): error C2223: left of '->storage' must point to struct/union
 ..\..\src\cylinder_plume_inccoriolis_viscosity_test.c(200): error C2065: 'dS': undeclared identifier
 ..\..\src\cylinder_plume_inccoriolis_viscosity_test.c(200): error C2065: 'eqn': undeclared identifier
 ..\..\src\cylinder_plume_inccoriolis_viscosity_test.c(200): error C2109: subscript requires array or pointer type
 ..\..\src\cylinder_plume_inccoriolis_viscosity_test.c(205): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '{'
 ..\..\src\cylinder_plume_inccoriolis_viscosity_test.c(211): error C2065: 't': undeclared identifier
 ..\..\src\cylinder_plume_inccoriolis_viscosity_test.c(211): error C2223: left of '->storage' must point to struct/union
 ..\..\src\cylinder_plume_inccoriolis_viscosity_test.c(212): error C2065: 'dS': undeclared identifier
 ..\..\src\cylinder_plume_inccoriolis_viscosity_test.c(212): error C2065: 'eqn': undeclared identifier
 ..\..\src\cylinder_plume_inccoriolis_viscosity_test.c(212): error C2109: subscript requires array or pointer type
 ..\..\src\cylinder_plume_inccoriolis_viscosity_test.c(151): fatal error C1075: '{': no matching token found

 Done.
```